# Mapping an arc in D3 using d3.geo.path()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to plot an arc connecting two points on a map of the USA. 
The code I have used to make the map of the usa is

```
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()
    .extent([[-98 - 45, 38 - 45], [-98 + 45, 38 + 45]])
    .step([5, 5]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

queue()
.defer(d3.json,'us.json')
.await(makeMyMap);



function makeMyMap(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b && !(a.id / 1000 ^ b.id / 1000); }))
      .attr("class", "county-boundary")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "state-boundary")
      .attr("d", path);

  drawPath()

}

function drawPath() {
var route = svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
                   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[33,-118], [38.6,-78]]})
                   .attr("class", "route")
                   .attr("d", path);
}
```

Currently the path that is drawn by the `drawPath()` function is being made somewhere, but I can't view it on the map. If I don't set `fill: none` in the CSS then the screen will be blacked out, but setting it to a colour just makes the canvas be covered by that color.

The us.json file is used to make the map and is a topojson object.

Comment: Could you provide a live example to fiddle around with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You screwed up the positions for your LineString. According to the [spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) positions are specified as `[longitude,latitude]`. Since values for latitude cannot exceed 90 degrees, it's obvious that you need to switch the order of your coordinate values:

```
.datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-118,33], [-78,38.6]]})
```

Thanks to the comment by Mark who took the time and made the effort this is also available in his [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ImhCNdtgkWDZH2O7uAED?p=preview).

Comment: beat me to it.  Here's a working [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/ImhCNdtgkWDZH2O7uAED?p=preview).

Comment: @Mark I have included a link to your demo in the answer. Hope, you don't mind.

Comment: Oh I can't believe I missed something like that. Thank you so much!